# .bash_profile setup after python was installed

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am setting up python environment on Mac (Catalina). I've installed python3 and wanted to launch it from terminal by typing "python".

```
epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec 13 2019, 18:00:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % python3
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I wanted to setup an alias for "python" to open python3, but .bash_profile wasn't there.
I've created it and added an alias, but my alias does not work

```
epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % ls -altr .bash_profile    
ls: .bash_profile: No such file or directory

epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % touch .bash_profile

epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % chmod 700 .bash_profile

epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % ls -altr .bash_profile 
-rwx------   1 epipko  staff     21 Apr  5 09:44 .bash_profile 

epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % cat .bash_profile
alias python=python3
```

Also, since python was installed before .bash_profile was created, am I missing python specific content in .bash_profile? Do I need to reinstall python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your alias like below within single-quotes:

```
epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % cat .bash_profile
alias python='python3'
```

EDIT-1: 
After adding the above in the file, run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bash_aliases` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

For example:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
$ alias python='python3'
$ python --version
Python 3.8.2

$ python
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % cat .bash_profile
alias python='python3'
epipko@Eugenes-Mac ~ % python

Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec 13 2019, 18:00:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: @epipko Added an EDIT-1. Please check.

Comment: This works. Will I have to run source ~/.bash_profile every time I restart my mac?

Comment: you only need to source the bash_profile or bashrc file when you make changes to it. not everytime when you restart. Please read [Purpose of bash_profile](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-the-purpose-of-bash_profile-file-under-user-home-directory-in-linux/)